# Python based tokenizers for non English languages

Tags: nltk, tokenize, spacy

We currently build text based models using scikit learn library in Python. Scikit learn has default support of tokenization for English laungauge. We want to add support for non-english languages as well (Spanish, French, German, Italian, Japanese, Turkish). I am looking for a python library that support above languages. I came across SpaCy and NLTK but I am looking if there are any other python libraries and if there is comparison chart in terms of benchmarking, memory usage, accuracy, support for multiple languages, stability and community support.
I found this https://spacy.io/usage/facts-figures but I am wondering if anyone did some research on other python libraries also and have a similar comparison chart so that it helps me in choosing a right library for my work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following ones. They should support German, French etc.

https://pypi.org/project/sacremoses/

https://pypi.org/project/mosestokenizer/